# SES how to get ARN of identity?

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-ses

How to get the Identity ARN of a verified SES email?
I have an SES email which is verified and I want to get the Identity ARN to assign it to Cognito programmatically. Looking into the Boto3 config I can not find any method giving me this information. The closest I get is [list_verified_email_addresses](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ses.html#SES.Client.list_verified_email_addresses), which just gives me the email if it is verified... no way how to get the ARN from that.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From Boto3 docs, there is no support to get the identity ARN. But you can construct it easily. Assuming you are in `us-east-1` (or get the region using Boto3):

```
account_num = '1234567890'
identity = 'john@myemail.com'
print 'arn:aws:ses:us-east-1:'+account_num+':identity/'+identity
```

ARN

```
arn:aws:ses:us-east-1:1234567890:identity/john@myemail.com
```

Comment: At the date when I write this message (30/10/2020) the ARN of each address is available in SES => Identity Management => Email Addresses => click on the address and the ARN will be noted in "Identity ARN".

Comment: @AntoninBeaufort but the question is about how to get the ARN `programmatically`